# Spring Security ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: spring-security

I just added Spring Security, and when I reach any pages, I should be redirected to the login page. The issue is that I get an ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. I guess it happens because the login page is secured and then it's redirected to itself, so the many redirects error. Here is my configuration:

```
<!-- Spring Security -->
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <!-- Login page is not secured -->
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/app/index.html#/login" access="true"/>
    <!-- The rest is secured by default -->
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <security:form-login login-page='/app/index.html#/login'/>
</security:http>
```

The root page is `/webapp/app/index.html`. The `webapp` is the Tomcat context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that browser does not send fragment part of the URL (`#/login`) to the server, therefore you cannot use it in your Spring Security configuration.

The easiest way to solve this problem is to create separate page for login form, such as `/app/login.html`.